# Tkinter canvas item placing coordinate system

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Can someone explain the coordinate system that tkinter shapes use on a tkinter Canvas?
I don't understand many of the coordinates.
Thanks.

EDIT: Could someone clarify this: A line uses (x0, y0, x1, y1), the starting and ending points. Rectangles, ovals, images, and text use (x1, y1, x2, y2), the top-left and bottom-right corners. And also, what does an arc use?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Refer to the [document](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M124) on the required arguments for each canvas item.

Comment: In addition to the up-to-date tcl/tk documentation indicated by acw1668, there is an old python version of [Tkinter's documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/index.html) (it does not contain the most recent methods  but the canvas methods have not changed)

Comment: Thanks! These sites helped a lot. I didn't see them before nor did I find them in any google searches.